# Is it possible to use “yet” with past simple?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-perfect-continuous

Is it common to use **“yet”** with Past Simple before Past Perfect Progressive? Or is it better to use Present Perfect?

Someone asked me :

> Why you hadn’t written earlier?

I think a specific time is implied in my answer ( and that’s the reason I should use Simple Past) but at all I don’t know which one is flawless.

> I haven’t written the letter yet because I had been caring for my sick
> mother all day.

Or

> I didn’t write the letter yet because I had been caring for my sick
> mother all day.

Source: *English Grammar Digest* by Trudy Aronson.

Dear administrators, I’m really sorry if there’s any grammatical mistakes in my topic, I've just started to learn English.

Comment: "Why you hadn’t written earlier?"  is ungrammatical.  It should be "Why hadn't you written earlier?".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the credentials of OP's source (Trudy Aronson), but so far as I'm concerned, any sentence of the general form *[subject] **didn't** [infinitive verb] **yet*** is inherently invalid (or at least, "awkward" compared to Past Perfect). Here's what [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/yet) has to say about it...

> *We use yet as an adverb to refer to a time which starts in the past and continues up to the present. We use it mostly in negative statements or questions in the **present perfect***. (emphasis mine)
> Warning:
> *We don’t use yet to refer to something that has happened. We use **already***

You can *just about* get away with ***Past** Perfect* in contexts like...

> *She had not yet left school when she married*

...where the "temporal focus" is on the time of marriage. Normally, ***yet*** goes with ***Present** Perfect*, with the temporal focus on ***now*** (time of utterance). But the word ***yet*** is completely unnecessary in my cited context, and it seems inherently clumsy to me anyway, so I'd just omit it.

Comment: Why do they use "did you eat yet" in songs and signs instead of "have you eaten yet" ?

Comment: Well, perhaps because you've been taught that's "incorrect", you're more likely to notice [the relatively lower number of occurrences.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+you+eat+yet%2Chave+you+eaten+yet&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Bear in mind native speakers don't learn how to talk from schoolteachers - they learn by listening and talking with *other* native speakers, many of whom don't know or care about stuff you were taught. We all tend to avoid Perfect forms *if we can*, but that particular example is much more common in America than Britain.

Answer (score 1):

*Yet* is perfectly acceptable and common in the past tense, especially in the present perfect. *Yet* most often means "up to the present/stated time". This could be in the present or the past tense.

In the examples above, the first reply is the better one.

> I haven’t written the letter yet...

This is because there is a temporal relation to the present. The second option would work if the question that you were asked were the following:

> Did you write the letter per our discussion yesterday?

In addition, I would use the same tense for both clauses:

> I haven’t written the letter yet because I **have** been caring for my sick mother **all day**.

This is because you use the phrase *all day* which continues to the present.

In terms of the use of *yet* with the simple past, there seems to be some division between what's acceptable to American vs. British ears. In US English, I find the following sentence completely natural and grammatical (Note: I speak of "grammar" in the more general term. That is, part of natural language use):

> No, I didn't send the letter yet.

One final note. The initial question that was asked of you could use some adjustment:

> Why **haven't** you written earlier?
> Unless there's missing context, the pluperfect doesn't work for this simple question. The present perfect is better.

Comment: Please accept my sincere gratitude for your clear and unambiguous explanations. They have helped me tremendously. I greatly appreciate people like you who teach from the heart. This website is the best teacher ever for students like me who aren’t able to pay tutors because of financial issues. Believe me our world is a better place because of you ... May all life's blessings be yours.

Comment: You don't seem to have addressed the issue of using anything other than *Past **Perfect*** for events that started ***and finished*** in the past - as OP's second example *I didn’t write the letter yet because I had been...*, which I don't really find acceptable.

Comment: Hm. This is grammatical to my American ears: "I didn’t write the letter yet because I *have had to care* for my sick mother all day." The problem I felt was with the tense of the second part of the sentence.